# Push Pull Power Amplifier Design

Tags: amplifier, push-pull

Below is the image of a pull push circuit but I'am exactly not familiar with it . May be class A or B or AB . But I was hoping if someone could tell me the name for this configuration

I'am known the voltage sources , output power , input impedance , voltage gain and the low frequency bandwidth cut off . My task is to find the values of RC components in the circuit above that will make the circuit behave according to the parameters given . Can some one tell me the equations to solve this circuit or more importantly a link at which I can read more about it . Thanks

Data : 
Supply voltages ± 9 V 
Voltage gain >20 dB 
Low frequency roll-off point < 100 Hz (Lower bandwidth limit) 
Rin > 2k ohms

Hint : Choose a suitable 
input signal voltage to achieve the specification

[image]

Comment: Try taking it apart: you have a CE amp (Q1), then an AB CC pp stage (Q2/3). The CC does not provide voltage gain, you have the gain, choose R1,2,5,3+4. Choose R4 provide a suitable voltage between Q2 and Q3 bases. And so on.

Comment: As @VladimirCravero says. Note, for small signal (AC) analysis, you should be able to see that R4,D1 can be ignored, so use the values of R3 and R5 when analysing Q1. (But include R4,D1 for DC analysis)

Comment: @BrianDrummond   can you people please take a moment and explain in detail as to how this is done . DC and AC analysis . It would do a lot good to my knowledge . I can not analyze this circuit .                                                                                  I know the following                                                                           Supply voltages    ± 9 V 
Voltage gain    >20 dB
Low frequency roll-off point    < 100 Hz (Lower bandwidth limit)
Rin    > 2k ohms

Comment: Do you know how to design a common emitter stage (Q1)? Do you know the working principle of the push-pull stage and the meaning of R4-D1 ?

Comment: First 2 chapters of "Art of Electronics" should cover what you need in enough detail to get you started. Nobody's likely to repost them here.